# std::call_once vs std::mutex for thread-safe initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm a bit confused about the purpose of `std::call_once`.  To be clear, I understand exactly what `std::call_once` *does*, and how to use it.  It's usually used to atomically initialize some state, and make sure that only one thread initializes the state.  I've also seen online many attempts to create a thread-safe singleton with `std::call_once`.

As **[demonstrated here](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2012/10/21/implementing-a-thread-safe-singleton-with-c11/comment-page-1/)**, suppose you write a thread safe singleton, as such:

```
CSingleton& CSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    std::call_once(m_onceFlag, [] {
        m_instance.reset(new CSingleton);
    });
    return *m_instance.get();
}
```

Okay, I get the idea.  But I thought that the only thing `std::call_once` really guarantees is that the passed function will *only* be executed once.  But does it *also* guarantee that if there is a race to call the function between multiple threads, and one thread wins, the other threads will *block* until the winning thread returns from the call?

Because if so, I see no difference between `call_once` and a plain synchronization mutex, like:

```
CSingleton& CSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (!m_instance)
    {
      m_instance.reset(new CSingleton);
    }
    lock.unlock();

    return *m_instance;
}
```

So, if `std::call_once` indeed forces other threads to block, then what benefits does `std::call_once` offer over a regular mutex?  Thinking about it some more, `std::call_once` would certainly *have* to force the other threads to block, or whatever computation was accomplished in the user-provided function wouldn't be synchronized.  So again, what does `std::call_once` offer above an ordinary mutex?

Comment: Did you try/test it?

Comment: @Brandon, Testing for race conditions can be impractical.

Comment: Why do you call `lock.unlock()` in your second example?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One thing that `call_once` does for you is handle exceptions.  That is, if the first thread into it throws an exception inside of the functor (and propagates it out), `call_once` will not consider the `call_once` satisfied.  A subsequent invocation is allowed to enter the functor again in an effort to complete it without an exception.

In your example, the exceptional case is also handled properly.  However it is easy to imagine a more complicated functor where the exceptional case would not be properly handled.

All this being said, I note that `call_once` is redundant with function-local-statics.  E.g.:

```
CSingleton& CSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    static std::unique_ptr<CSingleton> m_instance(new CSingleton);
    return *m_instance;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
CSingleton& CSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    static CSingleton m_instance;
    return m_instance;
}
```

The above is equivalent to your example with `call_once`, and imho, simpler.  Oh, except the order of destruction is very subtly different between this and your example.  In both cases `m_instance` is destroyed in reverse order of construction.  But the order of construction is different.  In your `m_instance` is constructed relative to other objects with file-local scope in the same translation unit.  Using function-local-statics, `m_instance` is constructed the first time `GetInstance` is executed.

That difference may or may not be important to your application.  Generally I prefer the function-local-static solution as it is "lazy".  I.e. if the application never calls `GetInstance()` then `m_instance` is never constructed.  And there is no period during application launch when a lot of statics are trying to be constructed at once.  You pay for the construction only when actually used.

Comment: But how is your example with the function local static thread safe?

Comment: C++11 specifies it to be thread safe. I know because I had to implement it for libc++abi. :-)  See 6.7 [stmt.dcl]/p4 of C++11 for the specification.  Warning:  VS-2013 does not yet implement thread-safe construction of function-local statics.  But everyone else does.

Comment: Wow.  C++11 really fixes a lot of the crap we had to deal with regarding thread-safety in C++03.  I'm so used to seeing function local statics and thinking "OMG NOT THREAD SAFE!"

Comment: Note that GCC supports a compiler flag to disable the abomination of threadsafe local statics, and note that some people (me, for example) have it added to default compiler options. Making local statics threadsafe without a way of communicating that this is not desired was an immensely stupid design decision. It mostly helps turning rare snippets of _bad and incorrect_ code into _bad but correct_ code, which is still bad. Thus `call_once` does have its merits. It gives a strong guarantee if, and only if you really need it, not when you actually don't want it. Still, nice answer :)

Comment: @Damon: Wow, you are the very first person I've heard say that you dislike the thread safe initialization of function local statics.  I must say that I use them all the time both at work and in my personal projects.  And prior to porting to VS-2015 at work, it was a major pita to work around the lack of them.  But thanks for sharing.

Comment: What operations would be required by the functor to _NOT_ work properly with the mutex (accessed via unique_lock)? I cannot imagine such code - if the functor fails with an exception, the mutex is unlocked and the next waiting thread tries to do the initialization. Exactly as with call_once().

Comment: @FreddieChopin: Agreed.  All of the implementations above are exception safe.

Answer (score 3):

Slight variation on standard C++ solution is to use lambda inside the usual one:

```
// header.h
namespace dbj_once {

    struct singleton final {};

    inline singleton & instance()
    {
        static singleton single_instance = []() -> singleton {
            // this is called only once
            // do some more complex initialization
            // here
            return {};
        }();
        return single_instance;
    };

 } // dbj_once
```

Please observe

- anonymous namespace implies default static linkage for variables inside. Thus do not put this inside it. This is header code.
- worth repeating: this is safe in presence of multiple threads (MT) and is supported as a such by all major compilers
- inside is a lambda which is guaranteed to be called only once
- this pattern is also safe to use in header only situations

Answer (score 2):

<s>If you read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once) you'll see that `std::call_once` makes no guarantee about data-races, it's simply a utility function for performing an action once (which will work across threads). You shouldn't presume that is has anything close to the affect of a mutex.</s>

as an example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

static std::once_flag flag;

void f(){
    operation_that_takes_time();
    std::call_once(flag, [](){std::cout << "f() was called\n";});
}

void g(){
    operation_that_takes_time();
    std::call_once(flag, [](){std::cout << "g() was called\n";});
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::thread t1(f);
    std::thread t2(g);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

could print both `f() was called` and `g() was called`. This is because in the body of `std::call_once` it will check whether `flag` was set then set it if not then call the appropriate function. But while it is checking or before it set `flag` another thread may call `call_once` with the same flag and run a function at the same time. You should still protect calls to `call_once` with a mutex if you know another thread may have a data race.

### EDIT

I found a link to the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2139.html) for the `std::call_once` function and thread library which states that concurrency is guaranteed to only call the function once, so it should work like a mutex (y)

More specifically:

> If multiple calls to call_once with the same flag are executing concurrently in separate threads, then only one thread shall call func, and no thread shall proceed until the call to func has completed.

So to answer your question: yes, other threads will be blocked until the calling thread returns from the specified functor.

Comment: no guarantee about thread-safety? `Executes the Callable object f exactly once, even if called from several threads.`

Comment: I'm confused.  The link you pasted seems to say the opposite of what you're saying: `No invocation in the group returns before the abovementioned execution of the selected function is completed successfully, that is, doesn't exit via an exception.`  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @BryanChen Yes, but it does not guarantee that there will not be a data race.

Comment: can you give some example?

Comment: I, too, read that link as guaranteeing the behavior of the mutex. Just, more concisely, just like C++11 std::remove_if (and a million other things) doesn't give you functionality you can't get _more verbosely_ otherwise.