# Realize a singleton-like functionality using std::call_once

Tags: c++, singleton, std-call-once

I want to realize a singleton-like functionality using std::call_once just for fun or perhaps could improve on the Singleton Pattern itself. Here's what I tried so far but I am stuck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
class single {
public:

private:
    single(){}
    friend void boo(unique_ptr<single>&);
};

void boo(unique_ptr<single>& f) {
    f.reset(new single());
}

unique_ptr<single>& bar() {
    static once_flag flag;
    static unique_ptr<single> f;
    call_once(flag, boo,f);
    return f;
}


int main()
{
    unique_ptr<single> f;
    f = move(bar());

    unique_ptr<single> f2;
    f2 = move(bar()); // this should not work but it does, work-around?
}
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985370/stdcall-once-vs-stdmutex-for-thread-safe-initialization

Comment: @FrederikDeRuyck: The link excepted an answer without call_once

Comment: As I read your code, the first time you call bar, the single tone will be returned, but the next time you call bar, bar return an empty unique_ptr, this is not usual.

Comment: @Oliv: Yes your are right, I try using a Static there. Wow it compiles at least. I want to hide boo() in a namespace. but after move(bar() in main() the instance in bar may be in problem

Comment: So now consider that the standard ensures that static locals to function (as is `f`) are only initialized once. So there is some form of code duplication here.

Comment: @Oliv: move(bar() in main should put the static unique_ptr<single> f in UB, but it works a second time

Comment: So I did not know you intented to do that, so go back to f non static.

Answer (score 2):

`static` is enough. [It does thread-safe initialization for you, no need for `call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables):

> If multiple threads attempt to initialize the same static local variable concurrently, the initialization occurs exactly once (similar behavior can be obtained for arbitrary functions with `std::call_once`).
>
> Note: usual implementations of this feature use variants of the double-checked locking pattern, which reduces runtime overhead for already-initialized local statics to a single non-atomic boolean comparison.

Hence:

```
unique_ptr<single>& bar() {
    static unique_ptr<single> f{new single};
    return f;
}
```

Or better:

```
single& bar() {
    static single f;
    return f;
}
```

Comment: Still I able to call bar() twice from main, any work around. I wanted to use std::call_once to achieve Singleton.

Comment: @ark1974 Yes, you can call `bar` multiple times. But if you move that smart pointer, it returns `nullptr` on subsequent calls.

Comment: Agree there; still I want to simplify entire pattern with std::call_oncce

Comment: @ark1974 Hmm..., that `call_once` looks more like a complication, rather than simplification.

Comment: @ark1974 Your question can be marked as duplicate either way.